# Jackson handle 3rd party java type

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am providing the ability to deserialize a list of entities returned from JPA, however the list type returned from JPA is DelegatingResultList which has no default constructor.

The implementation uses proxy beans with AOP where I intercept interfaces that extend a set of interfaces to provide basic queries.

I can easily fix this by checking in my aspect if the object type is DelegatingResultList and then copy to an ArrayList, but I don't want to have to do this for every single aspect that I'm covering.

I am using the default typing to set as a property like so:

```
objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY);
```

The json in the serialized format with my value wrapper looks like this:

```
{"@class":"my.wrapper.ValueWrapper",
"response": ["org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingResultList",
[{"@class":"my.entity.TaxInfoEntity","taxType":"01","taxVal":"0.07"}, ..."]]"}
```

I have read about using mixins and custom deserializers, but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work.

I have tried using a Mixin, but I have no reference to the ResultList property as it's not saved in the json. Not to mention it doesn't even kick in when it's trying to deserialize.

I have tried using a custom deserializer but again, this never kicks in when deserializing. Would I be correct in assuming the mixin and custom deserializer only kick in if you try to deserialize passing the class as the type?

This of course would be read only as it's a cached value. So my intention is to convert to an Arraylist instead. How would I achieve this using Jackson?

Comment: What exactly did you try? What didn't work about it?

Comment: I updated the question to answer your questions. Do I need to provide code? I deleted the code after it didn't work so I would have to code it up again.